# Initialise class without defining the optional values

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a question about initialising classes. I have a Profile data class which I want to initialise without defining the optional values. How can I do that? When I make data class as followed:

```
data class Profile(
  val id: Long,
  val email: String,
  val password: String,
  val photo: String?
)

val profile = Profile(id = 1, email = "", password = "")
```

My IDE is giving an error about that the photo is not defined. I also don't want to set a default value, cause it should be possible that the photo is null, and I don't want to override that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want it to be `null` by default, then you have to explicitly set it to null, there's no way around that. One aspect in which Kotlin purposely differs from Java is that no variable is ***ever*** given a implicit default value. Even if it is nullable, you are required to set it to null yourself.

```
data class Profile(
  val id: Long,
  val email: String,
  val password: String,
  val photo: String? = null
)
```

Comment: Aahw ok i'll do that. Thank you for your answer.